# Split Horizontally Python Array Manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I write a function named split which accepts three parameters a, b, c and then do the following.

- create a n dimensional array 'x' having first a natural numbers (use `np.arange` method).
- change the shape of x to (c, b) and assign to new array y.
- split the array y horizontally into two arrays, then assign it to i and j.
- display i and j.

I tried using `hsplit` and `array_split` methods and then assign it to i and j. But the output is not matching as given below.

```
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(20)
y = np.array(x)
z= y.reshape(10,2)
#a = np.hsplit(z,2)
(a,b)=np.array_split(z,2,axis=0)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Actual output:-

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]
 [8 9]]
[[10 11]
 [12 13]
 [14 15]
 [16 17]
 [18 19]]
```

Desired output:-

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]
[[ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]
```

Comment: print `x` and `z` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right with hsplit, the problem is just the shape is the other way around to get the desired output:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(20)
y = np.array(x)
z= y.reshape(2,10)
a,b = np.hsplit(z,2)
print(a)
print(b)
```

output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]
[[ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]
```